# Using Merge Join in SSIS to merge two similar tables

Tags: sql-server, join, ssis, merge

I have two tables on two different servers that have identical schemas.  For simplicity, let's say each table has 3 fields.  I am trying to create a SSIS package that takes the data from both tables and merges it into one recordset.

I added two OLE DB sources, which get the same three fields from the two tables.  I then have a Sort transformation on each, that then flows into a Merge Join.  I set the join type to "Full Outer Join" on the Merge Join.  I can select all six of the fields and see the output using a Data Viewer coming out of the Merge Join.

Let's say there were 25 records in each source table.  In the Data Viewer, I end up getting 50 records - 25 with NULL in the last three fields, and 25 with NULL in the first three fields.  I would like the output to be 50 records with data in only three fields.  What I am doing wrong here?  Should I be using some other sort of merge option?

I would greatly appreciate any suggestions on how to resolve what should be a simple task.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The output from the `merge join` you are using is correct since you're using a `full outer join`. To fix your problem, use a `merge` transformation instead of `merge join`. This will combine your two sorted data flows into one sorted data flow. You've already set up your data flow correctly from your description (it should look like this):

[image: SSIS merge transformation]

Documentation can be found here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141703.aspx

Comment: markmanguy - That worked perfectly.  I *knew* I was forgetting something simple.  Thank you very much for your fast response!